# Which exception should be caught if a few were thrown in a stack trace?

Tags: c#, exception

This stack trace was thrown:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request..
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (995): The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.
```

I want to catch exactly this exception, not general `{Exception ex}`

- Which one have I add to my catch?
- And which rule should be used here?
- Last (`SocketException`) or first (`TaskCanceledException`) should be caught?

Thank you!

Comment: `TaskCanceledException`.

Answer (score 3):

At the call site (the line of code that threw the exception), the top of the stack trace is the exception that was caught.

If you have code:

```cs
try
{
    Foo();
}
catch (Exception e)
{

}
```

And a call stack:

> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
>
> ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request..
>
> ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (995): The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.

Then your `catch` statement caught a `TaskCancelledException` with an [inner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception.innerexception?view=net-5.0) `IOException` which in turn had an inner `SocketException`. The layers of exceptions happened while `Foo` was executing (either directly or in methods, properties, etcetera called by `Foo`).

You can modify your block to catch only this exception:

```cs
try
{
    Foo();
}
catch (TaskCancelledException e)
{

}
```

As always, you should only catch exceptions that you can handle. If the method containing your `try/catch` block doesn't know how to retry/abort a canceled `Task`, then you should remove the `try/catch` block and let it throw the `TaskCanceledException` to be handled further up the stack.

If you need to examine the exception to see if you can handle it, you can modify your code to get access without disturbing the stack trace in the event you do have to [re`throw`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/throw#re-throwing-an-exception) it:

```cs
try
{
    Foo();
}
catch (TaskCanceledException e)
{
    if (e.Task.CheckSomething()) {
    
    }
    else {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Starting with C# 6.0, this can also be achieved using the [`when`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/when) keyword:

```cs
try
{
    Foo();
}
catch (TaskCanceledException e) when (e.Task.CheckSomething())
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Exception ex gives you the whole exception history from stacktrace you can figure out where the exception came from.

```
try
{
    Foo();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   var message = ex.Message;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that you should catch `OperationCanceledException`, not the `TaskCancelledException`.

The former is the [base class for the latter one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcanceledexception).

```
try
{
    Foo();
}
catch (OperationCanceledException ocEx)
{
  //TODO log and handle
}
```

[Here are some test methods](https://gist.github.com/StephenCleary/dfd2a8b0a50ea3040695) (written by Stephen Cleary) to demonstrate that you can always catch cancelation with `OperationCanceledException` independently how the Task was cancelled.